# Processing YUV I420 from framebuffer?

Tags: c, image, image-processing, video, yuv

I have a byte array named `buf`, that contains a single video frame in YUV I420 format obtained from a framebuffer. For every video frame I also have the following information:

```
Size (e.g. 320x180)
Stride Y (e.g. 384)
Stride U (e.g. 384)
Stride V (e.g. 384)
Plane offset Y (e.g. 0)
Plane offset U (e.g. 69120)
Plane offset V (e.g. 69312)
```

Concatenating multiple video frames in a file, and passing that with size information to a raw video decoder in VLC or FFmpeg just produces garbled colors, so I think the bytes in `buf` should be reordered using the information above to produce playable output, but I'm completely new to working with video so this may be wrong.

I which order should size, stride and offset information be combined with bytes in `buf` to produce a byte stream that could be played raw in a video player?

**Example:**

https://transfer.sh/E8LNy5/69518644-example-01.yuv

Comment: can you post/upload some sample data (complete frame)? the plane offsets look wrong. there is only 192 between U and V, which can't be right. the strides being somewhat larger than the width implies to me that there is padding.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Sure, I have added a link to a complete frame. I must admit it looks weird when looking at it in a hex editor, but this is what I get from the framebuffer?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/x4Ik5Gq this is the yuv file interpreted as one grayscale stream, 384 wide. 352 pixels wide usable data. data looks oddly shifted. I can't speculate on that yet. also the U and V **rows** appear to be **interleaved**. if it was U then V, we'd see two flat pictures stacked, not pictures side by side. if they were per-sample interleaved, we'd see one picture with some texture to it. a strange format. where does the data come from?

Comment: [this](https://www.linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis-old/yuv-formats.html) suggests that this format might be called `M420`. anyway, strange, but decodable.

Comment: does the second image on https://imgur.com/a/x4Ik5Gq look sensible, are the colors correct? usable data is indeed 320x180

Comment: those plane offsets now make sense... if combined with those strides. U is at 384*180 bytes, and V is 192 bytes later, which is one chroma line... and they're interleaved like that, and the offset and stride cause reading to skip over the other chroma component's line. I'll prepare an answer.

Comment: The second image is completely correct, a blue sky with some clouds. Looking forward to learn how you did that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The layout of the data seems odd but using the given offsets and strides, this is decodable as YUV.

First there are 384 * 180 bytes of luma.

Following are the chroma lines, each being 192 bytes long... but U and V lines take turns! This is accounted for by the strange offsets. U offset points exactly to after luma. V offset is 192 bytes further... and reading would leapfrog by 384 bytes.

Here's code that extracts those planes and assembles them as I420, for decoding with `cvtColor`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

def extract(data, offset, stride, width, height):
    data = data[offset:] # skip to...
    data = data[:height * stride] # get `height` lines
    data.shape = (height, stride)
    return data[:, :width] # drop overscan/padding

width, height = 320, 180

Yoffset = 0
Uoffset = 69120 # 384*180
Voffset = 69312 # 384*180 + 192

Ystride = 384
Ustride = 384
Vstride = 384

data = np.fromfile("69518644-example-01.yuv", dtype=np.uint8)

Y = extract(data, Yoffset, Ystride, width, height)
U = extract(data, Uoffset, Ustride, width // 2, height // 2)
V = extract(data, Voffset, Vstride, width // 2, height // 2)

# construct I420: Y,U,V planes in order

i420 = np.concatenate([Y.flat, U.flat, V.flat])
i420.shape = (height * 3 // 2, width)

result = cv.cvtColor(i420, cv.COLOR_YUV2BGR_I420)

cv.namedWindow("result", cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv.resizeWindow("result", width * 4, height * 4)
cv.imshow("result", result)
cv.waitKey()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: output]